# Can we connect markers in google Geo Chart

Tags: javascript, angular, google-visualization

Is there any way to connect markers in Google geo charts.
I have markers on the different areas in a graph I will one more point where it might be head of some markers so i need to connect them from this point.
Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: There is no in built feature to draw lines between markers in Google Geo Charts. In case you can make your use-case implementation in Google Maps its easy to achieve using the Polylines module. Else you have to use [VectorWorkz](http://vectorworkz.com/)

Comment: TY. The site is not working it seems. Do you have any other alternate?

Comment: You may [ZoomCharts](https://zoomcharts.com/en/javascript-charts-library/html5-charts/geochart/) but don't know whether the lines can be drawn in it.

Comment: I need exactly like this https://www.amcharts.com/demos/map-with-curved-lines/
Any known open source with this requirement. Currently using DEV Extreme charts but there also no in built feature it seems.

Comment: Actually you can use the free version of the Amcharts. It just displays the amcharts website link on the top left corner. [Mentioned Here](https://www.amcharts.com/download/)

Comment: TY. Amcharts are licensing. There is a option in dev extreme chart which matches my requirement.